# Meteor app stuck at 100% CPU when client loads - how to fix?

Tags: meteor

My meteor app has been hitting 100% cpu on the server when I load certain pages of the app on the client. It causes the app to hang for other clients. How can I fix it?

I suspect that I can improve performance by publishing or subscribing more efficiently for those particular pages. I am not sure, however, if doing more calculations in the publish functions to reduce the fields being sent to the client helps or hurts. While the data size being sent decreases, the number of calculations before sending the data increases. Should I optimize for more calculations and less data or less calculations and more data? Specifically, what criteria do I use to decide?

My publish function:

```
Meteor.publish('userdata', function(id) {
  if (!this.userId) return [];

  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if (!user) return [];

  if (isStaff(this.userId)) user = Meteor.users.findOne(id);

  var tasks;
  var emails = [];
  var network = user.users ? [user.users] : [];
  var meals;
  if (isStaff(this.userId) && this.userId === id) { //staff looking at own profile
    tasks = Tasks.find({users: this.userId, status: "active"}, {sort: { taskName: 1 } });
    emails = Emails.find({staffId: id});
    meals = Meals.find({userId: this.userId});
  }
  else { //staff looking at other profiles
    meals = Meals.find({userId: id});

    var completedTasks = [];
    if (user.userTaskStatus) {
      completedTasks = user.userTaskStatus.map(function (thisTaskStatus) { 
        if (thisTaskStatus.status !== "incomplete") return thisTaskStatus.taskId; 
      });
    }

    var allUserTasks = Tasks.find({users: user._id});
    var showTaskIds = [];

    allUserTasks.forEach(function (thisTask) {
      if (!thisTask.prereqs) showTaskIds.push(thisTask._id); 
      else {
        var prereqs = thisTask.prereqs;
        var pushTaskFlag = true;
        for(var i=0; i<prereqs.length; i++)
          if (completedTasks.indexOf(prereqs[i]) < 0) {
            pushTaskFlag = false;
            break;
          }
        if (pushTaskFlag) showTaskIds.push(thisTask._id);      
      }
    });

    tasks = Tasks.find({_id: {$in: showTaskIds}, visible: true, status: "active"}, {sort: { taskName: 1 } });

    var network = user.users ? user.users.push(id) : [id];

    if (isStaff(this.userId)) emails = Emails.find({userId: {$in: network}}, {sort: {date: -1}});

  }

  network.push(user._id);

  var calls = Calls.find({$or: [{to:user.phone},{from:user.phone}] });
  var callStaffIds = calls.map(function (thisCall) {
    return thisCall.staff;
  });
  var callNoteIds = calls.map(function (thisCall) {
    return thisCall.noteId;
  });

  var notes = Notes.find({
    $or:[
      {userId: this.userId},
      {noteId: {$in: callNoteIds}}
    ]
  });
  var noteStaffIds = notes.map(function (thisNote) {
    return thisNote.staff;
  });

  var allUserIds = network.concat(callStaffIds, noteStaffIds);

  var groups = [];
  if (user.groups) groups = user.groups;

  return [
    Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: allUserIds}}, {fields: {services: 0}}), 
    tasks,
    Groups.find({_id: {$in: groups}}, {sort: { groupName: 1 } }),
    emails,
    calls,
    notes,
    meals
  ];
});
```

Comment: Do you actually have any concrete data on which you base your assumption?

Comment: The cpu spikes only when I load certain pages of the web app in the browser. The publish functions associated with those pages have a lot of collection.find and for each loops

Comment: To me this code doesn't look right at all from a Meteor point of view. AFAIK you should be doing a publish per collection, not publishing an array of various arrays and cursors. Ideally in Mongo you'd have sub-collections. For instance the `Calls` collection would have a field called `notes` rather than a separate `Notes` collection. That way you just publish the calls and you get the notes returned. You can use something like underscore to pluck and flatten the notes from the array of calls. `var calls = Calls.find().fetch()` and `var notes = _(calls).chain().pluck('notes').flatten().value()`

Comment: @MichaelMason Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out. FYI nothing wrong with returning an array of Collection.Cursors, though that could be part of my problem. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish

Comment: @FullStack Ah well I've learned something new then! :)